# Python scripting for TeXworks

Tags: texworks

I searched on Google for almost a day and now I give up. I can't find any reference or manual for writing `TeXworks` scripts in `python`... Does anyone know how I can find these?

If no, what are the basis for writing `TeXworks` scripts? Maybe it is sufficient to get a collections of scripts written by other people and then learn from there..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Quote from the [MiKTeX mailing list](http://miktex.10937.n7.nabble.com/Is-there-a-TeXworks-refresh-command-td7889.html):

> ...some people told us that they way we included Python was unsafe and
>   prone to breaking some important Python functionality (at least on
>   Windows, IIRC). Since we didn't find anyone so far who could "make
>   things right", **Python support was removed** from the official builds for
>   the time being. Besides, up until now, scripting (almost) exclusively
>   concentrated on QtScript (which is pretty similar to JavaScript), so
>   there was no real demand for Python so far.

Comment: I didn't know that, thanks! The strange thing is that the `texworks-scripting-python` is still present in `ubuntu` repositories

Comment: http://www.tug.org/texworks also claims that "QtScript, Lua and Python languages are supported". Although the TUG homepage is almost never up to date about anything.

Comment: @marczellm I'll ask Karl to get that sorted